# How can I dump the entire Web DOM in its current state in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dom

I have a web page with some auto-generated javascript content which manipulates the DOM when users click on certain links.  When I save the page in Firefox, it just saves the *original* page without the DOM modifications.  How can I save or dump the *current* state of the HTML DOM as manipulated by the javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/6622/) has a `File->Save DOM As...` option.

Comment: Seems this is no longer supported "This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox."

Answer (score 2):

Looks like FireFox have replaced the DOM Inspector with a new tool that no longer has this functionality.

In the new DOM Inspector Ctrl + Shift + I there is a Console that accepts commands.

This sometimes works...

```
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML)
```

This gives you something you can inspect but not copy paste because of some bug...

```
alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML)
```

This works like console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML) ought to....

```
document.documentElement.innerText = document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: If you want a full HTML page, you could do something like:

    > console.log('<!doctype html>\n' + document.documentElement.outerHTML)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I now (Firefox 58 or so) opens Tools > Web Developer > Toggle Tools. In its Inspector tab, right-click on  `<html ...>` and choose Copy > Outer HTML, then paste into a text editor. That should grab everything in the current state of the page except the opening `<!DOCTYPE>` which you can copy separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use firebug to edit the DOM and save the full document markup.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be quite difficult; however, I found a Firefox add-on that works great.

**Save Page WE**
by DW-dev

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/

It is also available for Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 107, I just open up Web Developer Tools, choose the (DOM) Inspector window, right click the `<html>` tag, hover over Copy, and click on "Outer HTML".

Then I can paste it wherever I want.

No need for an extension or unmemorable code just for one-off usage.

Answer (score 0):

Select-All, Context Menu (right-click or [Menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)), `View Selection Source`.

In a few keystrokes: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>. Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (PC-style keyboard).