# Copy or export web page Element as html file... is that possible by any means?

Tags: html, google-chrome, puppeteer, devtools

LIKE UI answer in [Chrome Dev Tools export Elements HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151446/chrome-dev-tools-export-elements-html/28151765#28151765?newreg=c251ff023c3e420cb228d4e2abace15b)
is there any way/mechanism I can do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could use the [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property and the [`Clipboard.writeText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) API.

Comment: thanks mate for response... queried as its not that easy... am trying to get data from heirarchy like full xpath = /html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/iframe/html/body/iframe/html/body/div[2]/iframe/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3] and really not able to get it as a reasult of multiple random iframes in between so easiest for me is to inspect element > go back few keystrocks to find parent > right click > copy >copy element and paste as txt to work... this manual task in automation slowing us down hence trying to find a easier way to automate...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, then you must have to use jquery, it is the most easiest way!

First you have to include this script tag on the top of your Javascript file

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now because even a simple website contain plenty of HTML tags.

If you want to extract specific tag, you have to extract using the `ID` or `CLASS` of that tag

For example if i want to extract this tag from a website `https://example.com`

```
<h1 id='Header'>Example</h1>
```

I could simply take its Class name for fetching which is `Header`

Then using Jquery you can do like this

```
$.get('https://example.com/').then(function (html) {
// Success response
var $mainbar = $(html).find('#Header');
document.write($mainbar.html());
}, function () {
// Error response
document.write('Access denied');
});
```