# Element visible but not present in DOM

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I am using `Selenium` for HCI tests, but `Selenium` couldn't find an element that was visible, intrigued, I searched it and came to the conclusion that, the element is visible but not present in the DOM.

I may be mistaken (likely), but it's what it seems to be for me.

---

I have a website with an element, `Parcourir` :
[image: Element "Parcourir"]

When I click on it, I can see this `div` element:
[image: Navigateur de médias]

Here is the problem now, There is an element `Bibliothèque` at the top of the window, when I open the Browser Developer Tools, and inspect it, I find its id and XPath, the `element` HTML code is below:

```
<a href="#media-tab-media_default--media_browser_1"
data-tabid="media_default--media_browser_1" title="Bibliothèque" class="ui-tabs-anchor"
role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">
    Bibliothèque
</a>
```

But when I tried to download the DOM, just like its said in this answer:
[How can I dump the entire Web DOM in its current state in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147007/how-can-i-dump-the-entire-web-dom-in-its-current-state-in-chrome).

I can't find the above element in the DOM, I have an element that I can see in my Browser, which is not present in the DOM.
That's may be why selenium give me the `Exception`:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='ui-id-3']

Comment: see if its inside iframe

Comment: Yes! That was it, thank you. Should I post an answer and close the question? What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As element is inside iframe you have to switch to it first:

The syntax for switch to frame is

```
driver.switchTo().frame(id);
```

If you have multiple iframes and there is no id find each iframes uniquely as you do for other elements , using any other attributes like Id,class etc of the specific iframe

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class=\"class\"]")));
```

Now remember to switch outside the frame to interact with elements outside the iframe again.

```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Hello, the syntax should be webdriver.switchTo().frame(frameId); since it's Java. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @PDHide, the problem was that the element was inside a frame, I just switched to the frame, like below:

```
webdriver.switchTo().frame(frameId);
```

And it worked.